# rake jobs:work Each time I start my server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I am using delayed jobs, because I have some long running processes running in the background.
The annoying part is that I need to run 'rake jobs:work' before I start my application everytime.
Is there any way to let my Rails application know that I want it to start every time I restart my server? or refresh my homepage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this on your local machine? If so, you could just set an alias that you could run that would run 'rake jobs:work' when you use the alias. For example:

```
alias startserver='rake jobs:work & rails s'
```

Comment: Replace the `;` with a `&`.